# What is wrong about this arxiv latex bundle submission ? Please help I am out of mind?

Tags: texmaker, arxiv

I am trying to submit a article to arxiv that is perfectly compiled on texmaker but not in arxiv. There are many warnings around but no error at all. What might be the problem, if you dare to look all the lines linked below.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s146/sh/72b67292-b95e-4ed1-b27c-714fd1c39509/558fcb77e3fe50185fe38abe1008be8e

Any suggestion is really welcome!

Comment: Apparently, your archive includes a file `missfont.log` which arxiv uses as an indicator that something went wrong.

Comment: Also `fame_arxiv_2014.synctex` should not be included, and I _think_ `ieee.bst` shouldn't be either, since it is used to generate the bbl.

Comment: I would like to give all my points to you :)

Comment: @Erogol, has this been resolved then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments